# What is the proper way to insert tab in sed?

Tags: linux, sed

What is the proper way to insert tab in sed? I'm inserting a header line into a stream using sed. I could probably do a replacement of some character afterward to put in tab using regular expression, but is there a better way to do it?

For example, let's say I have:

```
some_command | sed '1itextTABtext'
```

I would like the first line to look like this (text is separated by a tab character):

```
text    text
```

I have tried substituting TAB in the command above with "\t", "\x09", " " (tab itself). I have  tried it with and without double quotes and I can't get sed to insert tab in between the text.

I am trying to do this in SLES 9.

Comment: Try using column (http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_column.htm) for this - it is a tool specialized toward columnizing data.

Comment: You should offer the solution as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: The `i` command takes the extra material on the next line of the `sed` script.

Comment: try escaping the back-slash. for example, this worked for me: `sed '1i\\\thello world'`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply use the `sed` `i` command correctly:

```
some_command | sed '1i\
text    text2'
```

where, as I hope it is obvious, there is a tab between 'text' and 'text2'.  On MacOS X (10.7.2), and therefore probably on other BSD-based platforms, I was able to use:

```
some_command | sed '1i\
text\ttext2'
```

and `sed` translated the `\t` into a tab.

If `sed` won't interpret `\t` and inserting tabs at the command line is a problem, create a shell script with an editor and run that script.

Comment: Your solution works along with @AaronMcDaid 's, so I'm curious why it also somewhat works when "\" is omitted? Is newline required after "\"?

Comment: It depends on the version of `sed`. Classically (meaning anything not using GNU `sed`) you have to use the backslash newline after the `i` command to specify the lines to be inserted. The last line without a backslash at the end marks the end of the inserted text. GNU `sed` does support, as an extension, the ability to specify the first line of inserted text immediately after the `i`; MacOS X `sed` does not. It depends on your portability criteria: if working with only GNU `sed` is OK, then the one line variant is OK; if you need to work on HP-UX, Solaris, AIX, MacOS X as well then be careful!

Comment: So is "\" optional in some variants or is it still an incorrect command even though it works for inserting text without tab character in it?

Comment: The `'sed -e '/^/itext\ttext2'` notation seems to work with GNU `sed` and embeds a tab.  So did the version with an actual tab in place of the `\t` escape sequence.

Comment: Another option is to prepare your scripts with printf.  For example ... `scr="\`printf '1i\\\ntext\ttext2\n'\`"` ... so that you can run `some_command | sed "$scr"`

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what you mean by "use the `sed i` command correctly", in addition to giving an example.  Also, it's not clear at all what you mean by "create a shell script with an editor" or how that would solve the problem.

Answer (score 27):

Assuming bash (and maybe other shells will work too):

```
some_command | sed $'1itext\ttext'
```

Bash will process escapes, such as `\t`, inside `$' '` before passing it as an arg to sed.

Comment: I like this solution, as it can be applied to many other instances where tab might be needed in a parameter.

Answer (score 5):

As most answers say, probably literal `tab` char is the best.

`info sed` saying "**\t is not portable.**" :

```
...
'\CHAR'
    Matches CHAR, where CHAR is one of '$', '*', '.', '[', '\', or '^'.
    Note that the only C-like backslash sequences that you can
    portably assume to be interpreted are '\n' and '\\'; in particular
    '\t' is not portable, and matches a 't' under most implementations
    of 'sed', rather than a tab character.
...
```

Answer (score 4):

escape the tab character:

`sed -i '/<setup>/ a \\tmy newly added line' <file_name>`

NOTE: above we have two backslashes (\) first one is for escaping () and the next one is actual tab char (\t)

Answer (score 3):

Sed can do this, but it's awkward:

```
% printf "1\t2\n3\t4\n" | sed '1i\\
foo bar\\
'
foo bar
1   2
3   4
$
```

(The double backslashes are because I'm using tcsh as my shell; if you use bash, use single backslashes)

The space between foo and bar is a tab, which I typed by prepending it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.  You'll also need to prepend the newlines inside your single quotes with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

It would probably be simpler/clearer to do this with awk:

```
$ printf "1\t2\n3\t4\n" | awk 'BEGIN{printf("foo\tbar\n");} {print;}'
```

Comment: I had to turn both "\\" into "\" for it to work and had to remove the newline after the last "\" because otherwise I would get an extra blank line in my output. Working command: `sed '1i\NEWLINEfooTABbar\'` (just replace NEWLINE and TAB with actual characters). Thanks for Control-V tip, as it allows me to type special characters like TAB into commandline.

Comment: Also seems to work just fine without the NEWLINE, so I am able to use: `sed '1i\fooTABbar\'` (just replace TAB with actual character).

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate the fact the [BRE syntax for `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-syntax.html) does mention that `\t` is not portable, Git 2.13 (Q2 2017) gets rid of it.

See [commit fba275d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fba275dc93319ffa31ecebe015f8cda671fcf0e5) (01 Apr 2017) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3c833ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3c833cae446364872b759c7622af2760a2f81a11), 17 Apr 2017)</sup>

> ### `contrib/git-resurrect.sh`: do not write `\t` for HT in `sed` scripts
>
> Just like we did in [0d1d6e5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d1d6e50cf3401874b50b77aa1dc0e33357a1556) ("`t/t7003`: replace `\t` with literal tab
>   in `sed` expression", 2010-08-12, Git 1.7.2.2), avoid writing "`\t`" for HT in `sed` scripts, which is not portable.

```
-   sed -ne 's~^\([^ ]*\) .*\tcheckout: moving from '"$1"' .*~\1~p'     
+   sed -ne 's~^\([^ ]*\) .*     checkout: moving from '"$1"' .*~\1~p'
                            ^^^^
                             |
                        (literal tab)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternate way to insert a tab by using substitution.

`some_command | sed '1s/^/text\ttext\n/'`

I still do not know of a way to do it using the insert method.

Answer (score 0):

This command replace `old` to `new` in file.txt:

```sh
sed -i '' 's/old/new/' file.txt
```

This command will add a tab for `new`:

```sh
sed -i '' $'s/old/\tnew/' file.txt
```

This command replaces an entire string:

```sh
sed -i '' 's/.*old.*/new/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the backslash with another backslash worked for me as @Noam Manos mentioned in his comment.

```
some_command | sed '1itext\\\tABtext'
```