# Incorrect escaping for regex expression in sed; I don't want a literal TAB, I want \t

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to run a script to modify `.bashrc` to insert the time in front of the command prompt. But I keep ending up with a literal TAB instead.

I have tried

```
sed -i "s/PS1='\${deb/PS1=\'\\t \${deb/" {filename}
sed -i "s/PS1='\${deb/PS1='\\t \${deb/" {filename}
sed -i "s/PS1='\${deb/PS1='\t \${deb/" {filename}
sed -i 's/PS1=\'\${deb/PS1=\'\\t \${deb/' {filename}
sed -i $'s/PS1=\'\${deb/PS1=\'\\t \${deb/' {filename}
```

and many variations of the above. I am usually getting nothing inserted ir an actual tab.

I have found if I do:

```
sed $'s/PS1=\'\${deb/PS1=\'\\t \${deb/' {filename} | grep PS1=
```

then I get output that appears to be what I'm after, but just not in the file.

**How do I insert an actual `\t` *and NOT a TAB* inline to a file I want to edit?**

In case it wasn't obvious, the last example above and the test on the command line use the same regex. Or at least, I think they do.

I was trying to change two lines in `.bashrc`. These lines pertained to the command prompt and are reproduced in full here:

```
~⟫ grep PS1 .bashrc
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
```

I want it to be converted to:

```
PS1='\t ${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
PS1='\t ${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
```

I think it is obvious, but, I don't want to insert a `TAB` into the line. I want to insert `\t` literally, that is, "backslash and t" together and not have them translate as a TAB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way to insert tab in sed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394066/what-is-the-proper-way-to-insert-tab-in-sed)

Comment: Sounds like the OP is trying _not_ to insert a tab!

Comment: `sed -e 's/pattern/\\t/g' /tmp/file >/tmp/newfile` works like a charm for me

Comment: I've tried the triple backslash, in both single and double quotes. I don't think I've tried the `-e` switch tho. The silly part is the last one works to std out, just not in line.

Comment: And thanks @Aaron for your thoughts, incorrect as tho they may be :) Tom (and my question) sums it up,  I don't want a tab. Please at least read the title in full (I haven't changed it) or at least skim the question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double-escape the `\t`:

```
 sed -i "s/PS1='\${deb/PS1='\\\t \${deb/" .bashrc
```

sed removes a level of escaping and will insert a literal `\t` in your file.

Comment: After revisiting this, I have changed the correct answer to be this one. Both answers are correct and I do like Tom's 'group' approach that I should do more often, but this is the exact answer I used, as such, thanks Ben :)

Answer (score 4):

As you're using double quotes around the sed command, you will need to escape the `\` as well, that is use `\\\t` in the replacement string. This is because the shell is transforming `\\` into `\` before sed sees it, so if you start with `\\t` then you end up with `\t` and sed inserts a tab.

If you were using single quotes around the command, then you wouldn't have to double-escape as sed would see `\\t`. However, it looks like your pattern contains single quotes.

At a guess based on your attempts, you need to use something like this:

```
sed -E -i.bak "s/(PS1=')(\\$\\{deb)/\\1\\\t\\2/" .bashrc
```

I've used capture groups to reduce repetition. The references to the captured groups need escaping too. I also added a suffix to the `-i` switch so that a backup of your original file is made.

If you show us the current line in your file and the desired output, then we can provide you with the exact answer.

Comment: I will add the full line when I get home, but it's basically the same command prompt setup from `.bashrc`. I could probably just get away with appending a prefix to it at the end of the script, it's just that I've always manually added it there. I think its all confusing by the characters in the line, namely `\t, \, $, {, ', "` and possibly others :)

Comment: refer the edit in my question, but it was the triple backslash. I'm going to go thru the bash history later, I KNOW I tried it, but it may have been behind single quotes or something else I'm not sure of. Notwithstanding, this is correct. Thanks :)